# Does Japanese have a term for toilets that use a rubbish bin for toilet paper?

Tags: word-requests

In some countries near Japan, such as Taiwan and Mongolia, there are sit-down flush toilets where you have to put toilet paper into a rubbish bin. Is there a term for such toilets? Would 台湾式トイレ (Taiwanese-style toilets) work?

Comment: Is there any toilet where you don't have the options between putting toilet paper into a rubbish bin or into a toilet? Your question is confusing. Do you have a definition of 台湾式トイレ? Have you been to all the Asian countries?

Comment: @Ranthony I don't understand why you're confused by my question, or why you ask if I've been to all the Asian countries.

Comment: (1) If you want to find out what is the equivalent in Japanese of an English word, you have to show us what you mean. Is it **squat toilet** or **sit toilet**? What do you mean by **sit-down flush toilet**? (2) What does **台湾式トイレ** mean based on your research? Does it have a special meaning? (3) Why Taiwan? Why not "モンゴリアントイレ"? (4) What makes you think you have to put toilet paper into a rubbish bin in only one type of toilet? You mean you can't put it into flush in squat toilet? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 4):

Japan does not have the concept of a non-flush toilet.  Even the port-o-potties at music festivals flush (including the TP).

Google searching "トイレットペーパー流せないトイレ" returns results such as "what countries have toilets that don't flush", "are there really places where you can't flush toilet paper", and "Why some foreigners don't flush toilet paper". None of them seem to have a word for it.  Also, consider that high volume tourist areas have instructions (often in Chinese only) on how to use the toilet... not some single, self-describing term.

I think you should just call it like it is, with the phrase above.